# Applying change of variable

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, network

I have the following function
$$R_\infty = \sum_k P(k)[1-e^{-\lambda k\phi_\infty}$$

which is the infinite time epidemic prevalence of a network model for some degree $k$ in the network with infection rate $\lambda$, the degree distribution of the network $P(k)$, and some function $\phi_\infty$ (this is no longer relevant). In an Erdos-Renyi random network with a Poisson degree distribution, for mean degree $\mu = pN$, $P(k)=\frac{(pN)^k}{k!}e^{-pN}$. So, the expression for $R_\infty$ in the continuous case becomes

\begin{align*}
R_\infty &= e^{-pN}\int \frac{(pN)^k}{k!}[1-e^{-\lambda k\phi}]dk\\\\
&= 1 - e^{-pN}\int \frac{(pN)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda k\phi}dk
\end{align*}

(since the sum of all degree probabilities is 1).

To solve this integral, I know I have to do a change of variable or something but I do not know how to proceed or how to choose what variables to change to make this a solvable integral (or at least something I could simplify for analytic interpretation). Perhaps I could let $x=\lambda k\phi$ but I don't know what else to change or how to solve this.

Comment: I don't understand why the degree $k$ suddenly becomes continuous; it makes the expression ill-defined, since $k!$ cannot be treated as continuous function (even if you can replace the factorial by the gamma function); Poisson distribution is not designed to be continuous. Moreover, you still computed the total probability as it was a discrete sum.

Comment: @Abezhiko, thank you that makes a lot of sense. I will ponder more on why the reference says to take its continuous form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of integration in order to compute $R_\infty$; indeed, one has :
$$
R_\infty 
   = \sum_{k\ge0} P_\mu(k)(1-e^{-\lambda\phi k}) 
   = 1 - e^{-\mu}\sum_{k\ge0} \frac{\mu^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda\phi k} 
   = 1 - e^{-\mu(1-e^{-\lambda\phi})}
$$

Comment: have you used a Taylor expansion on the series? Can you please elaborate more on this solution?

Comment: I used the exponential series, as follows : 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\mu^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda\phi k} 
   = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\mu e^{-\lambda\phi})^k}{k!} 
   = e^{\mu e^{-\lambda\phi}}
$$